# Syntax Error on Login in django

Tags: python, django

I am getting a syntax error on the last else statement, i don't no where i am not doing it right but am assuming its a result of an idention error. sublime text auto idention not helped me out:

```
@csrf_exempt
def pagelogin(request):
    context =RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
            if user.is_active:
                # If the account is valid and active, we can log the user in.
                # We'll send the user back to the homepage.
                login(request, user)
                #return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
                return render(request,'index.html')
            else:
                # An inactive account was used - no logging in!
                return HttpResponse("Your  account is disabled.")
        else:
            # Bad login details were provided. So we can't log the user in.
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")

    # The request is not a HTTP POST, so display the login form.
    # This scenario would most likely be a HTTP GET.
    else:
        # No context variables to pass to the template system, hence the
        # blank dictionary object...
        #messages.success(request, 'You have successfully logged in to your account')
        return render(request,'pagelogin.html')
```

Comment: Looks like your indentation isn't correct. Everything from `user = authenticate(...)` up to the last `else` should be indented one level.

Comment: Which `if` statement is that `else` supposed to be referring to? The initial one?

Comment: Yo have two elses here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indent like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def pagelogin(request):

    context =RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
                # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
                if user.is_active:
                    # If the account is valid and active, we can log the user in.
                    # We'll send the user back to the homepage.
                    login(request, user)

                    #return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')

                    return render(request,'index.html')
                else:
                    # An inactive account was used - no logging in!
                    return HttpResponse("Your  account is disabled.")
        else:
            # Bad login details were provided. So we can't log the user in.
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")

    # The request is not a HTTP POST, so display the login form.
    # This scenario would most likely be a HTTP GET.
    else:
        # No context variables to pass to the template system, hence the
        # blank dictionary object...
        #messages.success(request, 'You have successfully logged in to your account')
        return render(request,'pagelogin.html')
```

Comment: Thanks @tobifasc,  its now running well

Comment: On stackexchange you should avoid 'Thank you' comments but you can mark the answer as correct :)